# Why did my Canon 1000D stop working in full auto mode, when it still works in P, Av, etc.?

Tags: canon, autofocus, troubleshooting

It's my 7th day with my second hand Canon 1000D. But now, it's stopped capturing pictures in full auto, portrait, close-up, landscape, night portrait, sports, and flash off modes when used in autofocus mode. When I switch to full auto or scene modes in auto focus, my lens focuses but will not take a picture. In the creative modes like P, Av, etc. it works fine.

Comment: Is it possible for you to try with a different lens? This sounds very much like a lens issue rather than a camera one.

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to be wide spread. There are some advises in internet. Here is one of them (which seems to resolve the problem) from [here](http://forums.steves-digicams.com/canon-eos-dslr/180816-canon-eos-rebel-xs-1000d-auto-focus-problems.html):

> I was having the same issue on a Rebel XS - 3 years old, had been
>   working fine...
>
> Would not take photos on AF... just beeped, clicked etc...
>
> MF it would take photos no problem (though I was not actually
>   focusing)
>
> I googled the issue and found lots of suggestions on trying different
>   settings, cleaning the contacts etc... nothing worked and I was
>   resigned to buying a new camera or new lens
>
> Turns out it was the outer focus ring at the end of the lens that was
>   stuck - which makes perfect sense as it wouldn't take a photo since
>   the focus ring wouldn't move.
>
> Try this. Set it to MF. Hold the very end of the lens - (this is what
>   focuses the lens - the larger grip is the zoom) - give it a gentle
>   twist to see if it unsticks.
>
> If it does unstick, put it back to AF and try taking a picture.
>
> Voila! No reason to spend any $$ at a camera repair shop or buying a
>   new camera or lens! (though I have a feeling many camera repair shops
>   have made a killing by just twisting the focus ring free!)

P.S. I find this in internet and never test, so be warned

Comment: Surely this is very dependent on the make and model of the lens. Wouldn't it be better to set the lens to manual focus, and try focusing manually through the whole scale of the focus range? In my main lens, the focus is completely internal, the exterior does not move when focusing

Comment: You are right, it strictly depend of the lens. And as I mention I never test this way